# how to call date function in selenium rc using eclipse

Tags: selenium-rc

In my page have 3 calendars, i want to call calendar function from outside, 
how can i call that function from outside in selenium rc using eclips ide. 
i am new to selenium pls tell me how to write code for that and how to call that
function

```
for(int n = 3;n<=8;n++){
  for(int t = 1;t<=7;t++){
    String sday = selenium.getText("//div[@id='EZcalendar_table']/table/tbody/tr["+n+"]/td["+t+"]/a");
    int fday = Integer.parseInt(sday);
    if(cday == fday){                           
      selenium.click("//div[@id='EZcalendar_table']/table/tbody/tr["+n+"]/td["+t+"]/a");                            
    }   
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute arbitrary JavaScript on your page, use getEval().